How to improve word output for hugging face models?
I am running into a weird output involving the generative text AI models. I expect that the huggingface models that state to be similar to GPT-3, GPT-4 or llama would perform similar to the webUI counterparts that can be found on openAI or poe. However when I use them I end up receiving very strange and nonsensical output. Is there something that I am missing that is resulting in the output?
code
model_name = "EleutherAI/gpt-j-6b" # chatgpt-3 model
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
gpt_model = GPTNeoForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

max_length = 150
input_str = "Provide a list of five words that are similar to the phrase: 'Knights who say Nie'"
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input_str, return_tensors='pt')
attention_mask = torch.ones(input_ids.shape, dtype=torch.long)
pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id

with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = gpt_model.generate(input_ids, max_length=max_length, attention_mask=attention_mask, pad_token_id=pad_token_id, do_sample=True)
generated_text = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
print(generated_text)

attempt 1 output
(Nie = 'no').
A:
I think the answer is:
Nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie, nie

attempt 2 output
Nie can be found in the name of some of the most famous kings in history. The name of another king, Nieun-neng, was given by one of the best-known Chinese historians, the historian Tang Sanzang. The word 'Nie-neng' literally means 'the son of an uncle.' That means that Nieun-neng was the only son of King Nieun's uncle, Nio-neng.
Some kings began the use of the royal name from the moment they turned seven years of age and took the title of a 'Prince.' As a young child

here is the output from Poe that claims to be the ChatGPT-3.5 Turbo model
1. Warriors who declare Nay
2. Paladins who shout Nay
3. Guardians who utter Nay
4. Defenders who proclaim Nay
5. Sentinels who cry Nay


I've been playing with this model for a while myself and I can say that its performance is much worse than that of the GPT-3 or GPT-3.5-turbo
I think the main thing you are missing is the number of parameters. As I googled, the GPT-3.5-turbo has around 20b parameters, while GPT-3 has ~175b.
If you don't believe me you can also try some different models, like for example llama-2-7b, which has 7b parameters and yet its performance leaves much to be desired.
I may be wrong though! If someone more experienced comes into the chat, be welcome to correct me!

I have tried a couple different models hoping for improved outcomes. I started with GPT2, then tried T5, moved over to EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B. The model in the question is the most current model I am trying for text generation. And like with the current one, the older models I tested also generate some level of gibberish.
